# Would it be possible to restrict the commit in SVN until the Change Request WI is Approved

Tags: polarion

I am using Polarion ALM 20 and I am trying to achieve this use case:

- I would like to have restriction on SVN, that do not allow for commit unless a CR in Polarion is approved

Please advice how I can do this.

Thanks,
Sadanand

Comment: Part of a solution: write a pre-commit hook that checks for the CR, see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html

Answer (score 0):

In the Polarion SDK you find an example which is doing quite a similar thing you need:

> "[..] check, if the comment of commit message contains a link of work
> item, which have to be resolvable and not to be resolved. The idea is
> to ensure, that each revision will be linked to not resolved work
> item."

[polarion.example.commithook](https://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/examples/com.polarion.example.commithook/)